# Logitech F310 Gamepad Not Working

Tags: wine, games, steam, logitech

I decided to download DC Universe Online, which is supposed to work perfectly on linux, and the controller is supposed to work perfectly through steam. I downloaded DCUO by itself through wine and it downloaded fine but wouldn't recognize the Logitech F310 controller I plugged in. I tried downloading the game through steam which I had running through wine, and again the game worked but I couldn't get the controller to work. Does anybody have any advice?

EDIT: I just got xpadder to allow me to map it, so, as often happens when I post a question here, I may have solved the issue before anybody could get to it lol. I'll try to test it out and delete this if it works.

EDIT: okay after setting up the xpadder profile, xpadder registers everything just fine, but once the game is started up, it only recognizes the right control stick (which is bound to the movement of the mouse). All the other keys are ignored.

EDIT: After asylums link, I feel as though the problem may be with the xboxdrv layout, but I'm having difficulty finding the right configuration. The current setup is

`sudo xboxdrv --silent --detach-kernel-driver --trigger-as-button --ui-axismap x2=ABS_Z,y2=ABS_RZ --ui-buttonmap A=BTN_B,B=BTN_X,X=BTN_A,TR=BTN_THUMBL,TL=BTN_MODE,GUIDE=BTN_THUMBR`

Everything appears to work as intended except for the up/down on the right joystick.

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/828938354860178892/

Comment: that was almost the perfect solution. The controller works in game now for everything except to angle the camera up or down. My camera is stuck at the highest angle, looking almost straight up. There's likely a setting somewhere that I don't know about

Comment: Here is my explanation how to fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438422/22-04-the-xbox-controller-of-wine-has-a-mistake-how-to-fix/